# Magento 2 : 400 bad request Request header or cookie too large nginx Safari browser in ipad

Tags: ipad, nginx, cookies, safari, magento2

Only problem in safari browser in ipad when site visit 2,3 page after site not working after remove.
Browser cache site working after same issue.

> Error:      400 bad request Request header or cookie too large nginx

Comment: Use this article to debug and see what request comes when Safari is sending the request http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. If any one getting this error, just try to increasing the large_client_header_buffers directive in nginx

Ex:

```
server {
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
}
```